# AWS issued certificate connect to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, apache2

I am having problems connecting the AWS certificate manager issued SSL for a domain which is hosted on AWS EC2. How do I make sure the https works? Do I need to generate key and csr on server side and then submit it to AWS somehow? However, I do not see any option to interact with the AWS certificate manager in this way.

There is no tutorial of any kind on AWS itself. Thank you for your help.

I have added a load balancer with HTTPS enabled pointing to the EC2 instance and the AWS certificate. However, on trying to access https version of the domain in browser I get the page to error with the following: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must deploy an SSL/TLS certificate on your load balancer. The load balancer uses the certificate to terminate the connection and then decrypt requests from clients before sending them to the instances.

Here are the steps on configuring SSL on a Classic ELB.

[Configure an HTTPS Listener for Your Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-add-or-delete-listeners.html#add-listener-console)
[Configure Security Settings for an HTTPS Listener - ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-application-load-balancer.html#configure-security-settings)

Comment: Why is it not possible to add directly to an ec2?

Comment: At this time, Public ACM certificates can be used only with specific AWS services (ELB,Cloudfront) not on EC2.. https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/

Comment: what is the error do you get? you need to configure health checks as well.

Comment: It just does not connect or direct to the https version of the website. Do i need to set a record in the DNS for the domain name for the load balancer DNS address : http://gannak-484450630.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com/

Comment: your DNS is still pointing to the EC2 IP, you need to update the DNS to add  a CNAME record to point to the ELB's DNS

Comment: Ok, do I still need to enable ssl on ec2 and allow https for ec2 in the security group?

Comment: Not needed, ELB does SSL offloading

Comment: A record does not support ipv4, should I add it under a different tag?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html#routing-to-elb-load-balancer-configuring